# Rejection when removing remote branch on git

Tags: git, gerrit

When trying to delete a remote branch I get the following error:

```
$ git push work :18300-018_5
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
! [remote rejected] 18300-018_5 (can not delete references)
error: failed to push some refs  [...]
```

Any ideas what this means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like a Gerrit answer, as illustrated in the [function parseDelete()](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/source/browse/gerrit-server/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/server/git/ReceiveCommits.java?spec=svn2719faf576a500220d707c06862022f6186aebb6&name=v2.2.2-rc0&r=2719faf576a500220d707c06862022f6186aebb6#567).

```
  private void parseDelete(final ReceiveCommand cmd) {
    RefControl ctl = projectControl.controlForRef(cmd.getRefName());
    if (ctl.canDelete()) {
      // Let the core receive process handle it
    } else {
      reject(cmd, "can not delete references");
    }
  }
```

This is link to a [push policy controlled by Gerrit](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push).

> This category controls how users are allowed to upload new commits to projects in Gerrit.
>   **Deletion of existing branches is rejected. This is the safest mode as commits cannot be discarded**.

So unless you activate the "Force option" on this Gerrit category, you won't be able to delete a branch on that server.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of server is that? I guess it's not GitHub, but a custom server that was configured specifically to disallow branch deletion. Talk with your sysadmins about this issue.